# Can't start MongoDB service [Error: 1067]

Tags: mongodb

When I try to start my MongoDB service I keep getting the following message:

```
Windows could not start the MongoDB service on Local Computer
Error: 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly
```

MongoDB version: 2.6

Comment: Try running mongod.exe from elevated command line and see if you get more details.

Comment: Check if you have enough space on your hard drive. MongoDB usually requires 3-5GB of free space.

Comment: The docker image for Mongo is very easy to use, have you thought about using this rather than installing mongo?

Comment: Check the log files in Mongo directory. Usually provide a good idea. The windows logs provide zero idea.

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak and Chris, that's what I found on my logs: "ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files". Marek, please convert your comment into an answer and I'll gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue and the reason was that I didn't have enough free space on the hard drive.

MongoDB usually requires 3-5GB of free space.

If there is not enough space, the service will not start and you will see message:

> Windows could not start the MongoDB service on Local Computer
>
> Error: 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly